# Getting the integral from a graph

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

[image]

How do I get the area under the graph on each question. Ok so I see that a goes from 0 to 4 so I think it is everything underneath that. What is the area?

Comment: Hint: what shape is it? How can we find its area?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For exercise "a" you have to compute the following area:

[image]

I assume you know how to compute the area of a square and a triangle. Which is in the case of question "a" 4*2+0.5*4*4=16. Question b goes in a similar way.

Note that for question "c" you have to compute the area above the graph, since the graph itself lies underneath the x-axis:

[image]

Comment: What is the area of B i cant get it right

Comment: For B i got 40 but it says it is wrong i got C right though. Is it possible that the system is wrong?

Comment: B has to be 40 indeed. So if the system doesn't accept the answer, the system is wrong.

Comment: Thanks much appreciated

Comment: For "d" i got 24 but it doesn't say it is correct am I wrong or is the system

Comment: For "d" you have to add up your answer by "b" and "c" and add a little. Try to figure out what you did wrong.

Comment: You are the best

Answer (score 1):

For a, we are computing the area of a trapezoid, which evaluates to 16.

For b, break the shape into two shapes into a trapezoid, (from part a), a rectangle (of area 12), and a triangle (of area of 12), so we get 40.

c and d are similar, just remember that those "areas" will be negative.

Comment: I understand what u did but for B i got 40 as well but the system says its worng